# How many ways can we make inform passive?

Tags: grammaticality, get-passive

Is this sentence correct? "The results weren't informed us."

Comment: While I agree with the answers here, note that this sentence would be understandable if you dropped *us* from it: *The results weren't informed*. However, that would make *informed* an adjective and it would no longer be a passive construction. (It would be similar to *It was not an informed decision.*)

Comment: English Language Learners again.  The question is more suited for the English Language Learners SE site.

Comment: @Yasaman Semnani You could say, "the results weren't made known to us" or "the results weren't reported to us."

Answer (score 2):

No. Some other ways to say what you mean are "Nobody informed us of the results" and "We weren't informed of the results". The noun phrase "the results" is not an object of "informed". Not even indirect object. So the sentence in the OP is not grammatical.

Comment: The original sentence was " you did not inform us about the results" .would tell me the direct and indirect object?

Answer (score 1):

"The results weren't informed us."

You can indeed use 'inform' in the Passive voice and, according to a Cobuild Grammar reference it *is* more often used in the Passive in a *past* *context*. But here you are using what might be called Passive with Ditransitive. Swapping 'inform' with a number of others choices ("The results were given us") would be very informal.

"We weren't informed of the results." is a more common wording in the Passive.

---

(sorry https://english.stackexchange.com/users/318905/yasaman-semnani
I don't yet have the 'reputation' points to address your question.)

Comment: What about "The results weren't informed *to* us."?

Comment: @vinko-vrsalovic:  Because we don't "inform to"  There just isn't a preposition with 'inform' (unless you use the passive 'be informed by [someone]')

Comment: If you want to use this passive construction but you'd be happy with another verb, you could say "The results weren't told to us".  Several verbs can be used like this, e.g. "sent", "posted", "e-mailed", "forwarded".